# How to perform a query to return the number of rows that fulfils each column criteria

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called **Bookings** and the schema is as follows;

```
id | name | pizza     | country

1  | catA | pepperoni | USA
2  | catB | Sicilian  | USA
3  | catA | pepperoni | Greece
4  | catA | Sicilian  | Greece
```

How can I perform a query such that it returns for me the number of rows each value in  column appear.

Example;

```
name
catA | 3
catB | 1

pizza
pepperoni | 2
Sicilian | 2

country:
USA | 2
Greece | 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to use a group by statement for this type of query. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

A group by statement lets you use aggregate functions such as *COUNT()*.

```
SELECT name, COUNT(name) FROM Bookings GROUP BY name;

SELECT pizza, COUNT(pizza) FROM Bookings  GROUP BY pizza;

SELECT country, COUNT(country) FROM Bookings  GROUP BY country;
```

If you would like the output of all queries to be in a single result:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(name), 'name' FROM Bookings GROUP BY name
UNION
SELECT pizza, COUNT(pizza), 'pizza' FROM Bookings  GROUP BY pizza
UNION
SELECT country, COUNT(country), 'country' FROM Bookings  GROUP BY country;
```

Comment: thank you! but, I'd like to do this in **one** query.

Comment: @notTooOldToLearn Just remove semicolon from top two queries and add UNION operator between the three queries.

Comment: You'll need a UNION statement to combine the output SELECT queries together. I'll edit the solution to demonstrate this.

Comment: @MudassirHasan it works okay now. Is there a way to add a unique identifier to the returned values such that I know which column generated the groupby? currently, it returns data [(pepperoni, 2), (Sicilian, 2), (USA, 2)]. I'd like to return [(pepperoni, 2, pizza), (Sicilian, 2, pizza), (USA, 2, country)]

Comment: I've fixed up the answer you